# Can ionizing particles cause ignition of flammable material?

Tags: radiation, combustion

For example, can high energy $\alpha$ or $\beta$ particle cause ignition of $H_2/O_2$ mixture below critical conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Oxyhydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxyhydrogen) can be ignited with minimum of $20~\mu J$ spark energy. That would correspond to $\beta$ particle going at $0.999999999999999992~c$ speed or with $125~\text{TeV}$ relativistic kinetic energy. Needless to say that such highly energetic $\beta$ rays should be at scarse amounts in nature. However, if you would put $H_2+O_2$ mixture to be crossed by particles at LHC, at least theoretically it could ignite without reaching autoignition temperature.